# Customize Sharepoint Online Drop Down List Content

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a share point site for hosting documents with team members. There are a bunch of folders and respective sub folders. When I upload multiple documents at once, I can use the data view option to select which folder and sub folder I want them to be a part of using the same Data View. Only problem is when I click on the sub folder drop down to assign a sub folder, all the names of all sub folders I have created appear in the drop down list.I want this drop down to populate with only the  sub folders from the folder i have selected.

This is for a Sharepoint 2016 document repository.

Answer (score 0):

Something same type of implementation I have done. Where in a new form I want to filter out the Deactivated/Closed project for the Project Name Dropdown which is a lookup.

What I have came up is writing a custom script which I have put using a Script editor webpart and then using a rest call I am filtering the data.

You can achieve the same by adding a logic to call a JSOM or REST api to get the subfolders and then clear the dropdown and then fill in the dropdown with only the subfolders.

This is just a logic which I gave you.

Let me know if that helps